# Postgres Query with Hibernate Alias Doesn't Run

Tags: postgresql, hibernate, jpa

I'm using Hibernate/JPA in a Java app with a PostgreSQL 10 database.

The JPA-translated query below has errors:

```
select
    question0_.ID as id1_0_,
    question0_.LABEL as label2_0_ 
from
    public."QUESTIONS_T" question0_ 
where
    question0_.id=1
```

ERROR

```
column question0_.id does not exist
```

But everything looks syntactically correct. Does Postgres not support aliases?

[image]

Here's a PgAdmin window with a valid select from this table:

[image]

The queries are the same except #1 uses aliases. For reference, my entity model object:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "public.\"QUESTIONS_T\"") 
public class Question {

    @Id
    Integer id; 

    String label;

    @Column(name="ID")
    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Column(name="LABEL")
    public String getLabel() {
        return label;
    }

    public void setLabel(String label) {
        this.label = label;
    }   

}
```

Hibernate persistence.xml:

```
        <property name="hibernate.archive.autodetection" value="class"/>
        <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true"/>
        <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="true"/>
        <property name="hbm2ddl.auto" value="update"/>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect" />
        <property name="hibernate.connection.url"
                  value="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/postgres"/>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class" value="org.postgresql.Driver"/>
```